# Can someone provide me an example for Spring Data Couch Base 2.x client to store and retrieve data in Key Value format from couch base server?

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

My current project uses spring data couch base 1.2.3 Release version where CouchBaseClient object will be there to retrieve save/get data in key value format from couch base server/cluster/bucket. Now we are planning to upgrade spring data couch base version to 2.x, but CouchBaseClient object has been deleted in 2.x instead bucket/cluster beans are available. Bucket object doesn't have any APIs/methods to save/get data in key value format [ i might be wrong, not sure] so request to help me to find out how to proceed further is there a way in 2.x to store data in key value format?

we have plans to upgrade spring boot version to 1.4.4.release as well so if there are any others ways to interact easily with couch base server, please let me know.

My project env info:

Spring boot 1.2.3
Java 1.8

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: You will need Repositories to work with Spring Connector 2.x Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/ for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a factor of the underlying SDK being of a different generation (2nd generation of Couchbase SDKs, where most methods align in all languages/SDKs and the whole API has been made more coherent).

This generation of SDK exposes objects closer to the reality of the Couchbase cluster: `Cluster` object to connect to the nodes and perform cluster-wide operations, then `Bucket` to perform data operations.

Spring Data Couchbase 2.x builds on that. In your configuration you'll choose which `Bucket` to use (see the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/)) and as such you'll also be able to inject that `Bucket` instance if you really need to.

Note that Spring Data Couchbase offers several layers of abstraction on top of the SDK: repositories for CRUD operations around an entity type, then `CouchbaseTemplate` that offers individually typed operations but is still capable of marshalling to JSON (the SDK is accessible from CouchbaseTemplate).

On the other hand, with the SDK you have to marshall to JSON yourself, either as a `JsonObject` map-like structure (default) or a `String` (in which case you need to  store and retreive a `RawJsonDocument`). Working with these `Document` types is all explained in the [SDK's documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/sdk/java/start-using-sdk.html).